# How can a runtime value be a const?

Tags: c, operating-system, freertos

From the FreeRTOS include/StackMacros.h file:

```
#if( ( configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW > 1 ) && ( portSTACK_GROWTH < 0 ) )

#define taskCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW()                                                              \
{                                                                                                   \
    const uint32_t * const pulStack = ( uint32_t * ) pxCurrentTCB->pxStack;                         \
    const uint32_t ulCheckValue = ( uint32_t ) 0xa5a5a5a5;                                          \
                                                                                                    \
    if( ( pulStack[ 0 ] != ulCheckValue ) ||                                                \
        ( pulStack[ 1 ] != ulCheckValue ) ||                                                \
        ( pulStack[ 2 ] != ulCheckValue ) ||                                                \
        ( pulStack[ 3 ] != ulCheckValue ) )                                             \
    {                                                                                               \
        vApplicationStackOverflowHook( ( TaskHandle_t ) pxCurrentTCB, pxCurrentTCB->pcTaskName );   \
    }                                                                                               \
}

#endif /* #if( configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW > 1 ) */
```

If i understand it right, pxCurrentTCB is a kernel structure for running process and pxStack points stack beginning of that process. It is different every time but, somehow it can be stored in const value?

Comment: `pulStack` is `const` and it only lives inside the block it's declared, so why do you think this is a problem?

Comment: "*It is different every time but, somehow it can be stored in const value?*" <- well, in a *different* `const` object every time, so there's no contradiction.

Comment: `const` simply means that the object cannot be written to *after it has been initialized*; it has nothing to do with run-time vs. compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword `const` can mean two things:

1. If the `const` variable is initialized with a compile-time constant it is itself a compile-time constant.
2. If it's initialized at run-time then it's a *run-time constant*, which means once initialized it can not change its value.

Using `const` is also a good hint for readers of the code, but could also act as a hint for the compiler which might do some optimizations that might otherwise not be possible.

Comment: Why do you draw this distinction? AFAIK, it doesn't change the semantics of `const` at all which is just the value cannot be changed for the whole lifetime of the object...

Comment: Obligatory constant comment of yore: [... to give names to constants; instead of referring to pi as 3.141592653589793 ... `PI` can be given that value  This also simplifies modifying the program, **should the value of pi change**](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Fortran). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of `pulStack`:

1. The first `const` says that `pulStack` may *not* modify what it points to. (i.e.) `pulStack[0] = ...` is an error
2. The second `const` says that the value within `pulStack` (i.e. what it points to) may *not* be modified within the block scope in which it was declared. (i.e.) A [subsequent] `pulStack = ...` is an error